# How to set the dimensions of flash player in Flashdevelop?

Tags: flash

I use Flashdevelop.

How to set the dimensions of flash player in Flashdevelop?

Answer (score 0):

The size is given in Project/properties/output/dimension, but it can be overwritten by this line if placed in an actionscript file:

`[SWF(width="640",height="400",backgroundColor="#000000",frameRate="30")]`

with the values after the width and height being whatever you want the width and height to be.